# Inequality of independent random variables.

Tags: probability, inequality, expectation, conditional-expectation

In the following $P$, $E$ and $F$ respectively denote the probability, expectation operator and CDF.

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be three independent random variables. Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be the instances of these random variables. Then is the following statement true?

$$
P(x>y,x>z) = P(x>y)P(x>z)  \qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad (1)
$$

I understand that we can resolve it into the following form:

$$
P(x>y,x>z) = P(x>y|y>z)P(y>z) + P(x>z|z>y)P(z>y) \\
=P(x>y,y>z) + P(x>z,z>y) \\
= P(x>y>z) + P(x>z>y)\\
= E_{x,z}[F_y(x) - F_y(z)] + E_{x,y}[F_z(x) - F_z(y)]
$$

And maybe the last term is solvable. However, is there an easier way to solve the LHS of (1)? Particularly, is (1) true?

Comment: No.  Knowing that $x>y$ gives us some information regarding the size of $x$.  That information changes our view on the probability of $x>z$, so these events are not independent.

Comment: @lulu, I see. But how about viewing the same thing as $P(y<x,z<x)$ assuming that x is constant for the time being. Then will it not be $F_{Y,Z}(x,x) = F_{y}(x)F_{z}(x)$ from the definition of independence?

Comment: Not following.  As I say, these events are not independent.  I've posted an explicit counterexample below.

Comment: @lulu, Ok, thank you. Also, can you confirm if the second formulation (in the asked question) is correct? The one using the conditional probabilities and consequently the expectations.

Comment: Well, you are neglecting the probability that $z=y$.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for pointing that out. In my case however $P(z = y) = 0$.

Comment: That may well be the case (especially if you are working with continuous variables).  In that case I agree with the conditional analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  The events $x>y$ and $x>z$ are not, in general, independent.

An explicit example:  Suppose $X=\{0,10\}$, $Y=\{2,3\}$, $Z=\{4,5\}$. Say that in each case the probability of each outcome is $\frac 12$.

Then $P(x>y)=\frac 12=P(x>z)$ but $P(x>y,x>z)$ is also $\frac 12$.